# Walk through viewController hierarchy from other controller

Tags: uitableview, uiviewcontroller, hierarchy

i want to send a message to a tableView in another controller.
Actually i am in detalViewController.
The tableView i want to address is in DashboardViewController:

-UIViewController
--UIView
---**UITableView** *//i want to address this tableView.*

How can i do that?
In my DetailViewController IBAction i have this code:

```
NSLog(@"previousBtn");

DashboardViewController *parent = (DashboardViewController *)self.parentViewController;
NSIndexPath *actualIndexPath = selectedRow2;
NSIndexPath * newIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:actualIndexPath.row-1 inSection:actualIndexPath.section];
```

My aim is to set the new selectRowAtIndexPath:

```
[parent.tableViews selectRowAtIndexPath:newIndexPath animated:YES  scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionMiddle];
```

but parent.tableViews is not the correct way
Thanks for help,
brush51

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a workaround:

iam checking the subviews array and from NSLog i see the tablview was objectAtIndex:0. Then i have put that in an "if then else" and **do something** with the table.
In my case i do **selectRowAtIndexPath:** and **didSelectRowAtIndexPath:**

```
DashboardViewController *parent = (DashboardViewController *)self.parentViewController;

NSIndexPath *actualIndexPath = selectedRow2;
NSIndexPath * newIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:actualIndexPath.row-1 inSection:actualIndexPath.section];
//[parent.tableViews selectRowAtIndexPath:newIndexPath animated:YES scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionMiddle];

if([parent.view.subviews objectAtIndex:0]) {
    NSLog(@"drin!");
    UIView * subview = (UIView *) [parent.view.subviews objectAtIndex:0];
    UITableView *tView = (UITableView *) subview;

    [tView selectRowAtIndexPath:newIndexPath animated:YES scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionMiddle];
    [tView.delegate tableView:tView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:newIndexPath];
}
```

Hope someone can use this code and save a lot of time for try and error :)